# Python Introspection: Defining dynamic class methods during runtime

Tags: python, reflection, introspection

I'm trying to create a unit test, that checks that every function in `mymodule` has its own `TestCase` instance.
To reduce boiler-plate code and manual effort I wanted to use introspection/reflection to dynamically add `lambda` functions as class methods to the initially empty class `Test_TestCases`.
The following code kind of works - it does indeed add lambdas as class methods and `unittest.main()` finds and correctly calls them.

```
import unittest
from unittest import TestCase

import mymodule

class Test_TestCases(TestCase):
"""Class whose test_* methods will be created during runtime."""
    pass

################################################################################

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for item in dir(mymodule):
        attr = getattr(pws, item)
        if callable(attr):
            testname = "Test_%s" % item
            setattr(Test_TestCases, "test_%s_is_tested" % item,
                    lambda self: self.assertTrue(testname in globals()) and
                    issubclass(getattr(globals(), testname), TestCase))
    unittest.main()
```

The problem is, that all tests succeed even though I do have untested functions in my unit test module.
After a little trying around I figured out that the variable `testname` has the same value every time the `lambda` is called.
I could minimize the problem to this piece of code for reproducability:

```
lambdas = []
for i in range(5):
    lambdas.append(lambda: str(i))
print ", ".join(f() for f in lambdas)
```

I'd expect this output:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

but instead I get:

```
4, 4, 4, 4, 4
```

It seems that the lambdas are initialized lazily.
Could anyone please explain this behaviour or give me a hint on how I would accomplish my goal properly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That goes in the same direction and solves my reproducer, but my initial problem is something else.
Providing a default value wouldn't and couldn't fix my problem, because it's not the argument passed to the lambda function that always stays the same, but it is `testname`, a simple variable that is not passed as an argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shadow `testname` with another wrapper function:

```
def assertion(testname=testname):
    def function(self):
        return self.assertTrue(testname in globals()) and issubclass(getattr(globals(), testname), TestCase))

    return function

setattr(Test_TestCases, "test_%s_is_tested" % item, assertion())
```